# Keep AnyLogic Export simulation settings

Tags: anylogic

my model starts at a certain time (01.07.2022), but when I export it into the AnyLogic Cloud, the simulation starts at the real time date (01.02.2023). Is there a way to keep the settings from the Simulation?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You need to setup your RunConfiguration accordingly.

(AnyLogic experiments are NOT uploaded to the cloud at all.)

Instead, you use the RunConfiguration for that:
[image]